# How can I add values from a foreach loop into SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, service

I have an SMS app in the form of a windows service, I need to iterate through a collection containing the messages stored on the GSM modem's sim card, However my current code will not compile with the following error;

`Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'`

I have attempted to nest my SQL commands within the foreach loop, but this as mentioned will not compile, could anyone help?

I do intend to Parameterize by the way! this is just a proof of concept!

code is below

```
 private void SMSGetter()
        {

            Log("Getter Fired");

            //var message = GSM.ReadMessage(4);
            //GSM.ReadMessage(4);
            //TcpClientChannel client = new TcpClientChannel();
            //ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(client, false);
            //string url = "*********************";
            //ISmsSender smssender = (ISmsSender)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ISmsSender), url);

           try 
           {

               DecodedShortMessage[] messages = Comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);
                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*********;Initial Catalog=********;User ID=**********;Password=**********");
               SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
               com.Connection = Conn;
               Conn.Open();
               foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
               {
                   com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES ('" +message.ToString + "', 'Yes')");
                   com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
               }


               Conn.Close();
                return;
           }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Log(ex.ToString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: Missing Parens; `message.ToString()`

Comment: Well, you'd need to call `DecodedShortMessage.ToString()` (note the missing brackets in your code). Whether that returns a relevant string or not I don't know.

Comment: please use `sqlparameter` in parameterized queries.

Comment: Also this should be a parametrized insert; see what happens if there is a `'` in the message string.

Comment: And read http://bobby-tables.com to learn about SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: @DanielKelley that's not entirely true, because that would only return a string representation of the class name

Comment: My two cents: [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: I didn't mean you should literally call DecodedShortMessage.ToString() - I was pointing out your missing brackets like everyone else.

Comment: My bad, but thankyou! I can't believe I missed something like that!

Comment: @Jon Skeet Yeah, that advice cost me days before I recovered from that site..  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
               {
                   com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES (@par1,@par2)");
                   com.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@par1",message.ToString());
                   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2","Yes");
                   com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parens after `ToString`.

```
'" +message.ToString() + "'
```

As Jon points out, it would be better to use parameters instead:

```
com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES (@Message, @Blacklist)");
SqlParameter messageParam = new SqlParameter("@Message", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 8000);
SqlParameter blacklistParam = new SqlParameter("@Blacklist", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
messageParam.Value = message.ToString();
blacklistParam.Value = "Yes";
com.Parameters.Add(messageParam);
com.Parameters.Add(blacklistParam);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Or preferrably use parameterized SQL.

Comment: There's no "of course" about it when your answer just enables the OP's code to go from "broken but safe" (because it won't run) to "runnable but incredibly dangerous". This is *not* the change that the OP should actually apply to their code.

Comment: I absolutely cannot believe I missed this, thanks guys! also I do intend to parameterize this when the code is put into production!

Comment: @Reece: Never wait until "when the code is put into production" to address SQL injection attacks. It's much better to just do it right first time - generally the code ends up being cleaner anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon, One more thing if I may; my code throws another exception now saying apparently the SQL I've written has incorrect syntax, but I can't see how?

Answer (score 0):

your Command Text should be

```
com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES ('" + message.Tostring() + "', 'Yes')");
```

Comment: Indeed... but this is nowhere near helpful I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

First, use brackets after `ToString` (it should look like `ToString()`).

Second. Use `Parameterized` `SQLCommands` to protect from SQL Injection Attacks. Instead of

```
foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages) {
    com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO SMSArchives(Message,Blacklist) VALUES ('" +message.ToString + "', 'Yes')");
    com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

use

```
foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages) {
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SMSArchives (Message, Blacklist) VALUES (@par, 'Yes')", , connection)) {
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par", message.ToString());
       command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```